# How to add a new object to a nested object in reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to add a new object to a nested object in reducer ?
I have this object the current behavior is a new action simply overrides, the previous action but my goal is to add that array at the end ? and please any general guidelines how to simply deal with the state ? I know the following the state is immutable thus it has to be copied using the spread operator , as you can see in the code I did copy twice still there must by another copy missing but I have no clue where I experimented but no positive. if I add ...(state.item[action.grandParentId] ?? []),
under [action.grandParentId] I get really close but it copies the targeted object instead of updating.

```js
//initial state
items : {}

// State Action
  const AddItem = (select, id, idparent, grandParentId, index) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_ITEM,
      ITEM: select.item,
      id: id,
      idparent: idparent,
      grandParentId: grandParentId,
      index: index,
    });
  };
```

```js
   // ADD ITEM
        case ADD_ITEM:
          return {
            ...state,
            Items: {
              ...state.Items,
              [action.grandParentId]: [
              ...(state.exercises[action.grandParentId] ?? []),
                {
                  [action.idparent]: [
                    ...(state.Items[action.idparent] ?? []),
                    {
                      index: action.index,
                      id: action.id,
                      item: action.item,
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          };
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Didn't shallow copy the "grandParentId" array. Can you share what the initial state shape is so we can see what you are updating from, and also an example action object?

Comment: I did actually but it copies the whole targeted object instead of adding the the ending array, which is very close to what I want yet not quite

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the code and added a pic of the results from console. so the target results must be ( 0 position ) must have an array of 2 instead of one and the duplication should not happen at that end point.

Comment: Can you share your *actual* state shape so we know what is nested and where? Also, in that image it seems you've two elements with the same object key, is this expected? In the image, is the "9532c4d..." key the "grandParentId" and the "81c4cdd...." id the "idParent"?

Comment: @DrewReese 9532cd4 is the grandparent , and 81c4cdd is the item that is getting duplicated instead of looking like 81c4cdd : Array(2), everything is working as expected but the duplication at the end is the problem the point behind all of this is to have many grand parents ! , and many parents , each parent will have an array of items inside

Comment: @DrewReese yes drew i updated the image to show more details about the situation problem is I need to copy the state to be able to add the grand parent yet I don't want the duplication could this duplication be prevented somehow ?

Comment: Ok, I think I finally wrapped my head around your data structure. Do you have some example state and action values I could use to create a test case to ensure without a doubt my answer is correct? If not I can can try to fake some but would prefer actual data you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell you need to also shallow copy the "grandparent", but in this case since you are updating an exiting element of intermediate state you need to map the array to a new array, replacing the element with the matching id.

```
// ADD ITEM
case ADD_ITEM:
  return {
    ...state,
    Items: {
      ...state.Items,
      [action.grandParentId]: (state.Items[action.grandParentId] ?? []).map(
        item => item[action.idparent]
          ? {
            ...item,
            [action.idparent]: [
              ...(item[action.idparent] ?? []),
              {
                index: action.index,
                id: action.id,
                item: action.item,
              },
            ],
          }
          : item
      ),
    },
  };
```

Comment: I am trying but it is returning an empty array ?

Comment: @Connective-tissue Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-add-a-new-object-to-a-nested-object-in-reducer-9ys65?file=/src/App.js) that I think demonstrates this reducer case working.

Comment: btw drew is this pattern in general good ? I mean this from of deep nesting ? I was thinking today that I can reference the grandparent in the child to avoid nesting ? what do you think about this in general ? appreciate the effort you are a life saver.

Comment: @Connective-tissue Yes, [immutable updates](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) are the recommended pattern for updating nested state. If you update to using [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) (*it's incredibly simple to add to an existing project, BTW*) however, you can write your reducers in a mutable way and it handles the immutability for you.

Comment: @Connective-tissue What made your state a little more difficult to work with was the intermediate array of objects where each object had no standard id property, thus requiring a map operation and checking each object if it had a matching key. It would be better to convert this to an object and just use the `parentId` as the key. Combine with redux toolkit makes for an update that looks more like `state.Items[action.grandParentId][parentId].push(newItem)`.